# How can I see XSLT errors?

Tags: google-chrome, xslt

I am building some XSL files, but the development goes pretty slow.

Whenever a XSL file has a bug, Google Chrome does not display any errors: neither on the screen nor in the Developer Tools. It just shows a blank page and it's up to us to guess what went wrong.

Do I miss anything? Is there a sane way to do XSL development?

Comment: You can try debugging your XSLT here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/

Comment: The XML IDEs like oXygen, Stylus Studio or Altova XMLSpy that allow XSLT development and debugging. Also, Chrome uses libxslt so you could run xsltproc also using libxslt from the command line to get better diagnostics.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, many bugs in XSLT stylesheets do not actually result in errors, they simply result in incorrect output, very often blank output. This will happen, for example, if your template match patterns are incorrect (e.g. if you get the namespaces wrong). If your stylesheet is legal XSLT but produces the wrong result, then you're not going to see any errors on the developer console; and indeed few tools will give you much help in this situation.

Schema-aware XSLT was developed as an attempt to address this problem, but it's not going to help you much if you want to run stylesheets in the browser.

A big step forward in XSLT 2.0 was to allow type declarations on variables and parameters. If you use this feature, your bugs will often show up as type-checking failures. The native XSLT processors in the browser only support XSLT 1.0, but you could consider adopting [Saxon-JS](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml) (alternately, [npm "saxon-js" package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saxon-js)), which provides XSLT 3.0 support in the browser.

I would recommend doing as much of the development and testing as possible outside the browser environment, using an XML IDE such as Oxygen.